# Better way to code this Ruby class with similar functions

Tags: ruby

I have coded this Ruby code. Everything here works perfect as intended, however it is a real mess. What would be the best way to clean this up with best practices and such?

```
  class new_class
    attr_reader :shop_id
    SECRET_API_KEY = "asdasdasQWRESFSDFVSDFASDFSADFASDF123123ASDASD$%$%"

      def set_shop_id(shop_Id)
           @shop_id = shop_Id
      end

      def orders
         params = Hash.new
         params[:basic_auth] = {username: SECRET_API_KEY, password: ''}
         orders_json = some_http_library.get("xyz/orders", params)
         return JSON.parse(orders_json)
     end

    def products
        params = Hash.new
        params[:basic_auth] = {username: SECRET_API_KEY, password: ''}
        products_json = some_http_library.get("xyz/products", params)
        return JSON.parse(products_json)
    end

    def product(id)
        params = Hash.new
        params[:basic_auth] = {username: SECRET_API_KEY, password: ''}
        product_json = some_http_library.get("xyz/products/#{id}", params)
        return JSON.parse(product_json)
    end
end
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: I wouldn't store your API key in a class. Use environment variables.

Comment: You should not repost an identical copy of a question that has been closed, nor should you create a second account to do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Returns aren't necessary in Ruby. The last line gets returned out of methods.
2. You create the same has every time. The creation of that Hash could be a private method itself. If it only needs to be created once and will not change during the lifetime of this class' lifecycle, then you can create it upfront in a constructor or just store it in a instance variable.

If I had to rewrite it, it would look more like this:

```
class NewClass
  SECRET_API_KEY = "asdasdasQWRESFSDFVSDFASDFSADFASDF123123ASDASD$%$%"
  attr_reader :shop_id

  def initialize(shop_id)
    @shop_id = shop_id
    @params = auth_params
  end

  def orders
    retrieve_resource_from_url "xyz/orders"
  end

  def products
    retrieve_resource_from_url "xyz/products"
  end

  def product(id)
    retrieve_resource_from_url "xyz/products/#{id}"
  end

  private

  def retrieve_resource_from_url(url)
    response = some_http_library.get(url, @params)
    JSON.parse response
  end

  def auth_params
    {
      basic_auth: {
        username: SECRET_API_KEY,
        password: ''
      }
    }
  end
end
```